Can the edge degeneracy in spin-$2$ AKLT go away on an arbitrarily small $SO(3)$-symmetric bulk perturbation?
I am learning about SPTs, or symmetry-protected-topological phases. There is a rich structure in antiferromagnetic spin chains. The Heisenberg point is gapless in half-integer-spin antiferromagnets and gapped in integer-spin antiferromagnets. There's a difference between odd integers and even integers, in that the former is identified with a nontrivial SPT of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ while the latter is identified as trivial.
There's a special $SO(3)$-symmetric point in integer spin-$S$ chains called the AKLT point (named after Affleck-Kennedy-Lieb-Tasaki; see e.g. this Wikipedia article and references therein). This point has "spin-$S/2$ edge modes" and a ground state degeneracy of $(2*(S/2) + 1)^2 = (S+1)^2$ in open boundary conditions.
Suppose I maintain $SO(3)$ symmetry and add an arbitrarily small, extensive bulk perturbation. Am I guaranteed to maintain the spin-$S/2$ edge modes when $S$ is an even integer? That is, in the space of local $SO(3)$-symmetric Hamiltonians, is there an open ball about the spin-$S$ AKLT model that has spin-$S/2$ edge modes when $S$ is even? Or do these edge modes go away immediately?
